# Opengl in 500 lines point in triangle question

Tags: graphics, graphics-programming, rasterization, triangulation, barycentric-coordinates

https://github.com/ssloy/tinyrenderer/wiki/Lesson-2-Triangle-rasterization-and-back-face-culling

I am on lesson 2 of the `"Opengl in 500 lines"` tutorial. I follow the part of the lesson in `"The method I adopt for my code"`, but I don't understand this leap from

```
P = A + uAB-vector + vAC-vector
```

to

```
0-vector = uAB-vector + vAC-vector + PA-vector.
```

[image]

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4322/check-whether-a-point-is-within-a-3d-triangle

Comment: if I understand if you have `P = A + uAB + vAC` and you substract `P` on both sides then you get `0 = A + uAB + vAC - P` but `A - P` can mean vector `PA`

Comment: this is it, make it the answer and I'll check it

Comment: I'll break out the second part of my question into a new one, I should have just started with the question that was just answered

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand if you have

```
 P = A + uAB + vAC
```

and you substract `P` on both sides then you get

```
 0 = A + uAB + vAC - P
```

and you change order

```
 0 = A - P + uAB + vAC
```

but `A - P` can mean vector `PA`

```
 0 = PA + uAB + vAC
```